# How do you run ActiveRecord `find_each` to a materialized view in postgres

Tags: postgresql, rails-activerecord, materialized-views

Because I am pulling thousands of records from my materialized view `Matview`, I'd like to use `find_each` to break it up into batches to free up memory.

However, when I run the following:

```
Matview.where('p_id > 100').find_each {|m| m }
```

I get the following eror:

```
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
```

Upon research I found that you cannot run `find_each` on a table without a primary key.

I tried adding a Unique ID to `Matview` using:

`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_mv ON matview(p_id)`

while that was successful, that didn't substitute for a primary key.

I tried adding a primary constraint to my materialized view using the following:

`ALTER MATERIALIZED matview ADD CONSTRAINT mv_pk primary key (p_id) disabled`

But that failed.

So generally, my question is, how do I run `find_each` on a materialized view, and maybe specifically, how do I add a primary key to a materialized view so that I can run `find_each`?

EDIT: For clarity, I do not have an `id` column in `Matview`.  If I had one, I hear that it might be recognized by active record as a default primary key, but I have not tested that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ActiveRecord` doesn't care whether it is really a primary key in the database or not, but you need to set the `primary_key` field on your object using the [primary_key=](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/PrimaryKey/ClassMethods.html#method-i-primary_key-3D) method.

So something like:

```
class Matview < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = 'MATERIALIZED_VIEW_NAME_HERE'
    self.primary_key = 'ID_COLUMN_NAME_HERE'
end
```